# shell_exec already enabled but still needs to be enabled

Tags: php, ffmpeg, shell-exec

I am using PHP v7.2 and currently installed CMS that has a function thats automatically watermarks video via FFMPEG.

It runs FFMPEG with 'shell_exec'.The 'shell_exec and exec' has no local value but still it does show in the script/php that shell_exec has been disabled due to security reasons. I already contacted the server and they said also that it is enabled shown in PHPINFO but I'm getting an error to execute FFMPEG.

FFMPEG goes like this >

```
$cmd = shell_exec("$ffmpegPath -ss 00:00:01 -i $convertUrl -c copy -t 00:00:04 $xVideoFirstPath 2>&1");
$cmd = shell_exec("$ffmpegPath -i $convertUrl -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1 $videoTumbnailPath 2>&1");
```

Error shows when uploading a video :

```
Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/zxc/domains/zxc.com/public_html/requests/request.php on line 307
```

Answer (score 1):

As these functions allow code to be directly executed on a server (beyond just PHP), they are commonly restricted by hosts. If you're on a shared hosting plan, then this is most likely what's happened.

Even though the extension is installed, it has been disabled using the PHP `disable_functions` directive.